What Equivalent %* of Batch in PowerShell
Batch Script:
@echo off
if not "!!"=="" setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=4*" %%a in (
'dir /AD "%USERPROFILE%\" ^| find "DIR" ^| Find /v " ."'
) do if "%%b"=="" (set $dirs=!$dirs!"%%a" ) else (set $dirs=!$dirs!"%%a %%b" )

call :getmaxlen !$dirs!
echo Dirs !$dirs!
echo maklen '%max%'
pause 

:getmaxlen
set var=%*
for %%a in (!var!) do (
    set #L=%%~a
    for /L %%a in (0 1 100) do if not "!#L:~%%a,1!"=="" set len=%%a
    set /a len+=1& set "$Lens=!$Lens!!len! "
)
for %%a in (!$Lens!) do (
    if not defined max Set max=%%a
    if %%a GTR !max! Set max=%%a
)
exit /b

PowerShell Script:
function demo {
    $dirs = (gci $Home -Directory -force).Name
    getmaxlen
    "max len $max"
    pause 
}

function getmaxlen {
    $var = $dirs
    #$var =???
    $Script:max  = ($var | Measure -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
}

demo

From Batch Script above, what is equivalent of set var=%* in PowerShell call function ?
I mean equivalent of %* in PowerShell. $var =???
So. I can use Powershell function getmaxlen every time i need.

Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. Please read Can I answer my own question?

Thank you for the advice

There is no comparison between the mechanisms of batch and PowerShell for
passing arguments.
Basically, PowerShell uses two built-in variables :

$args
for undeclared parameters.
$PSBoundParameters
for the declared parameters.

Some references that can get you started :

How to Use Parameters in PowerShell Part I
How to handle command-line arguments in PowerShell


Thanks for the reference

based on an answer in the post: What is the Powershell equivalent for bash $*?
function demo {
    $dirs = (gci $Home -Directory -force).Name
    getmaxlen $dirs
    $max; pause; CLS 
    $dirs = (gci / -Directory -force).Name
    getmaxlen $dirs
    $max; pause; CLS 
    $dirs = (gci $env:Windir -Directory -force).Name
    getmaxlen $dirs
    $max; pause; exit 0
}

function getmaxlen {
    $var = $args | foreach {$_}
    $Script:max  = ($var | Measure -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum
}

demo

in CMD, %* represents all arguments, in PowerShell it is $Args, one of automatic variables.
$var = $args | foreach {$_}

So. function getmaxlen can be called repeatedly
